# Definition of the notation $C_c^\infty (I)$?

Tags: real-analysis, notation

What is $C_c^\infty (I)$ where I is an interval in $\Bbb R$?

I think it can be:

1. The set of all infinitely many times differentiable functions $f:I\to \Bbb R$ where $\{ x\in I \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$ is compact.
2. The set of all infinitely many times differentiable functions $f:I\to \Bbb R$ where the closure of $\{ x\in I \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$ in I is compact.
3. The set of all infinitely many times differentiable functions $f:I\to \Bbb C$ where $\{ x\in I \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$ is compact.
4. The set of all infinitely many times differentiable functions $f:I\to \Bbb C$ where the closure of $\{ x\in I \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$ in I is compact.

which is correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you have both $g$ and $f$? The answer is

$$ C_c^{\infty}(I) = \{f:I \to \mathbb F \mid \text{$f$ is infinitely differentiable with compact support} \} $$
where $\mathbb F$ could be $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Which one will depend on the author, and the author should really specify. If they haven't, $\mathbb R$ would be my best guess. Also remember the support of a function is the *closure* of the set on which it is non-zero.

Comment: the support is sometimes defined by $\{ x\in I \mid f(x) \ne 0\}$ and its closure is called closed support. confusing!

Comment: Yes it can be confusing. If it helps, when we say a function has compact support we usually just care about the support being contained in some compact set, no matter which definition you take. Also note here that by continuity of $f$, $\{x \in I \mid f(x) \neq 0\}$ is in fact open so can't be compact in $\mathbb R$ (unless it is empty).